# Can freeze spray be used for pc dust cleaning?

Tags: cleaning, dust

I've bought freeze spray instead of compressed air by accident. Can I use it as an alternative to clean dust from my pc?

Comment: I sure would not use it on my PC.  I did computer repair for  a living for a while.

Comment: Please provide a link to this thing you refer to as "freeze spray" - it could be any one of a number of products

Comment: Welcome to LifeHacks, fryz! You are asking whether a lifehack that you came up with will work. On this community, people ask for members to _suggest_ lifehacks. For example, "How can I put sunscreen on my own back?" We prefer that kind of question over yes/no questions like yours, which is why you've gotten two "close" votes. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

It probably would clean off dust BUT:

- The temperature drop of components could lead to condensation on the surface, which could kill some of your hardware if the water shorts some contacts. So I would keep an eye on that an wait until everything is ensured dry.
- If the spray contains chemicals that cause corrosion of contacts you could run into troubles after a while.
- If the spray contains chemicals that are arggresive to plastic or gaskets it could cause your mounts to become brittle, rubber bearings to become stiff, coils to short out.

***So check whats in the can. For example "Tetrafluoroethane" and "dimethyl ether" should be safe. But some Ethanols that maybe contained to prevent ice building up could cause corrosion of the upper problems.***

Look for the warning signs on the can and check with [GHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHS_hazard_pictograms)